Unable to get Windows 11 Installer to see the SSD on my Asus Zenbook (Q425MA) laptop
I'm at my wits' end with attempting to install Windows 11 on my Asus Zenbook (Q425MA) so that I can resell the laptop. No matter what I do the Windows 11 Installer is NEVER able to detect my Zenbook's SSD. Right now it has nothing installed, and just boots to BIOS.
I tried all of these things:

I formatted my laptop's NVMe SSD to NTFS format in a live USB Fedora boot with gparted, and it has a location of /dev/nvme0n1p1. I even made sure to create a gpt partition table before creating the NVME volume.
I disabled secure boot in BIOS (and tried enabling it again)
I enabled/disabled the VMD controller
Attempted to install ASUS IRST drivers, but the "Load Drivers" feature of the installer could not "see" the drivers on the thumb drive to install them.
I even booted into a live USB Linux boot, and deleted the NTFS volume again, and re-created the 'gpt' partition table

Am I missing something? What else can I try? Is there something else in BIOS I should tweak or enable/disable? I know it's not the case of the NVMe drive itself failing, because I can install Linux distros on it just fine--it's just the annoying Windows installer that cannot see the SSD for some reason.
Should I just give up, and install Linux on the laptop before I sell it? Should I try to install Windows 10 or 7 on it instead?
Forums/posts I've checked already with solutions that did not work:

Windows 10 Installer doesn't see SSD!
Cannot Find Drives when Installing Windows on Your Laptop | ASUS SUPPORT
Cannot find drives when installing Windows 11 or 10

Update:
People in the comments were asking for more details about the laptop and BIOS settings:
2024 Asus Zenbook Q425MA

Model: Q425MA-U71TB
SKU: 6568761
Serial #: S1N0CXxxxxxxxxx
BIOS Version: 305
GOP Version: 22.1.1035
UEFI Version: UX3405MA.305
EC Version: F01132C2.30B
Windows 11 ISO: Win11_24H2_English_x64.iso
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 7 155H
Memory: 16GB RAM

As far as the configuration for the BIOS settings, I've tried almost everything (including the default settings). So I'd love to share the BIOS settings, but I think it's pointless because I've tried almost everything already.
@Ramhound, in the comments, mentioned Intel RST being enabled, so I will look at that.



Unless you have Intel RST enabled, you don’t need the Intel RST drivers when you install Windows, so that is guaranteed to have nothing to do with your issue. If Windows was already installed, you can just Reset Windows, and choose to “Keep Nothing”. This is a really good option if you’re not unfamiliar with installing Windows. However, if you are familiar with the process, make sure CSM is disabled and all partitions on the drive have been deleted. You should make sure Secure Boot is enabled not disabled. You should make sure absolutely no partitions exist in the disk.

We need more information, screenshots showing your firmware settings, will be necessary. How did you create the installation media? What version of Windows 11 are you trying to install? Does the system meet all requirements for Windows 11?

I tried many variations of the BIOS settings. I want to update the BIOS firmware version, but I'm not sure how to do that. The firmware update from the site looks like an EXE file that does no good from inside of BIOS itself. I spent many hours messing with all of this, so my patience is running thin. I'm thinking to just take a hit and sell it as-is, or with Linux on it, at this point

I am more than willing to diagnose the situation but I need an adequate amount of information to do so.

Thank you. I will see what I can dig up about the BIOS and firmware, and then I will edit the question.

@KJ - Intel RST drivers are all required if Intel RST is enabled. If drivers cannot be provided the simplest solution is to disable it, it’s absolutely possible unnecessary to streamline the driver into the ISO. It’s necessary for Intel Optane but Intel Optane isn’t required.

@Ramhound - I updated the question to include more details. Btw, I created the bootable USB using macOS (wimlib in a terminal to split the large install.wim file so that it could write to a FAT32 drive). I don't think there's an issue with the USB since it boots to the Windows Installer screen just fine.


Yes, the installation media should be fine. That said, consider Ventoy for future projects (no need to split files and the USB media is usable as a mass storage device for the remaining space). 2. Start by changing the drive mode to AHCI instead of any "RAID" or Intel RST. It should be as simple as this to have the target drive recognized by the installer.

